# Understanding lm Multiple R when fit is a horizontal line

Tags: r, lm

I have been using R and the lm function to do linear regression and report R2.

```
y  = c(1,2,3,4)
x  = c(1,2,3,4)
f  = lm(y~x)
r2 = summary(f)$r.squared
```

However, someone gave me this case-

```
y = c(1,1,1,1,1)
x = c(75,33,50,33,50)
```

Excel reports an intercept of 1, coefficient of 0 and Multiple R and r2 of 1.
R reports an intercept of 1, coefficient of 01e-17 and Multiple R-squared of 0.3392

Not being a statistician, I'm not understanding where `lm()` gets that number for Multiple R-squared from. Could someone help me out with an explanation?

If I change the data to

```
y = c(1,1,1,1,1)
x = c(1,1,1,1,1)
```

Excel still gives y = 1 + 0 * x  r2 = 1

whereas `lm()` reports the slope as NA and does not report a Multiple R-squared.

While this seems like a unique case, I'm still being told my program that calls `lm()` does not work because it fails these tests and Excel gives the 'expected' answer.

Thanks

Comment: I think you may be misreading R's output. When I run that example, R does in fact report an intercept of 1. And the difference between a coefficient of 0 and 1e-17 is not meaningful in the context of the machine's tolerance.

Comment: As for your very last example, I would suggest that you ask your interlocutor how exactly Excel divined a slope from only one point (1,1)? Perhaps they need to revisit some basic high school geometry.

Comment: I was not asking about the slope and the intercept. I was asking about the Multiple R value that is returned. If the value of y is a constant, then I can get a fit that is simply y = c, independent of the value of x. In Excel, a Multiple R and an r2 are reported as 1. I assume this is because the line is an exact fit. In R, a Multiple R2 is reported as 0.3392. I have been unable to find an explanation anywhere that explains why the R2 should be 0.3392. The other point I was trying to make was Excel always reports r2 = 1 for y = c and R's Multiple R2 is all over the place depending on x. Why?

Comment: The R2 values are nonsense in both cases and have no real meaning, because the examples being run have zero variation in the y values. So the difference is probably entirely due to how Excel handles floating point arithmetic. It's dividing a really small number by a really small slightly larger number and getting one (!!), while R is dividing a really small number by a really small slightly larger number and getting a fraction. I know which makes more sense to me.

Comment: Also please note- I said "R reports an intercept of 0, coefficient of 01e-17" so saying "R does in fact report an intercept of 1. And the difference between a coefficient of 0 and 1e-17 " is saying the same thing. I assumed readers would recognize that my concern was the fact that while the slope and intercept were the same, the R2 were wildly different. Which is why I said ' I'm not understanding where lm gets that number for Multiple R-squared from. Could someone help me out with an explanation?' and the title is 'Understanding lm Multiple R.'

Comment: There's no need to get defensive. As I said, in the case of zero variation in the y values, R2 doesn't really make sense. You'd calculate it by essentially dividing 0 by 0. Any deviation from that would be floating point error. And I was simply pointing out what I thought was a typo. Saying that Excel gave an intercept of 1 and that R gave an intercept of 0 implies they got different coefficients (the intercept is a coefficient), which they don't.

Comment: OK. I was thinking of R2 as 1 - unexplained variance of which there is none with y = c. There is no variance. So using SSR/SST to calculate that would certainly give nonsense numbers. I'll try that and see if that correlates with the reported R2. I thought maybe R was being very clever about handling the case if zero slope. I guess not.

Comment: I was a little defensive because of the -1 given to my question. I generally assume if R and Excel disagree, there is some fine statistical point that R recognizes that Excel does not, so I asked. As I said- not a statistician and I was being beaten up by people that used Excel to indicate the lm result was wrong.

Comment: Well, I actually didn't down vote, but I can categorically say that it is Excel that is wrong in this case. The R2 squared issue is at least debatable, since in some sense it should be undefined. But Excel reporting a 0 slope in the last example is just flat out wrong. Good luck convincing them, though.

Comment: Thanks. Since I have a dialog box that reports slope intercept and R2 (from lm). Would you suggest I check for a very small slope and report no R2 (vs reporting R2 = 1)? I clearly need to do more than report the number summary(fit)$r.squared returned.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would summarize the very helpful, but long series of comments related to my original question which I will restate as: what is the appropriate value of r2 when y does not vary, i.e., the y data can be exactly fit to the equation y = c?

a. Excel reports an r2 of 1. Which is what my users want, since the data is fit exactly.

b. The r2 value should reflect the fraction of variation accounted for by the model as compared with that accounted for by the null hypothesis, i.e., the mean. The equation is

```
R2 = 1 - SSR/SST
```

where SSR is the sum of the squared distances between the actual and model (predicted) values and SST is the sum of the squared distances between the actual and mean values.

When the data exactly fits a horizontal line, there is no deviation from the mean. So asking what proportion of the deviation is accounted for by the model is actually meaningless. From the equation, one is dividing 0 by 0.

The values reported by R are thus likely to be nothing more than round-off error in values that are effectively zero.

I should therefore check for this condition and not report an R2 rather than either report the number coming from R (lm) or report the value that Excel would give (1).